# Android Service only runs whilst debugging

Tags: java, android, service, synchronization, broadcastreceiver

**Background**

I am creating a service that syncs a local Realm database (stored on phone) with an online database. The database stores users and measurements.

I initialise the service by calling 'startService(new Intent(this, SyncService.class));' during the splash activity's onCreate() method, and specify in the manifest that the service should run for the length of the application.

The service has a broadcast receiver. When the receiver detects a network change from 'not connected' to 'connected', it fires a method called syncDatabases().

This method finds all measurements recorded locally after the timestamp of the last API callback, and sends them to the database. The API responds to a request by returning the object + a unique ID.

When a measurement is made whilst the device is offline, it is stored locally. When an internet connection is made, the syncDatabases() method should be called in order to update the online server with the local measurements.

**My steps...**

Steps when debugging the project:

With wifi I open the app and with an external device make a new measurement. This appears on both the app and in the database. I then turn wifi off and make another measurement - this appears on the device.

I attach the debugger.

I turn back on wifi and this triggers the services' receivers' onReceive() method. I step through this and it all works according to plan. I reach the syncDatabases() method, and from there I receive the callback from the API, and it then updates the Realm database with the new ID value.

**The problem...**

If I don't attach the debugger, nothing happens. The new measurements aren't pushed to the database, and none of my Log.e calls are printed.

**Why is this happening? And is there an alternative solution / fix for this problem?**

**Code**

***Service class***

```html
public class SyncService extends Service {
    
        private static final String TAG = "SYNCSERVICE";
        private boolean mConnected = false;
    
        private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
    
                    final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    final NetworkInfo netInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    
                    if (netInfo != null) {
    
                        switch (netInfo.getState()) {
                            case CONNECTED:
                                if (!mConnected) {
                                    Log.e("NETWORK", "Network " + netInfo.getTypeName() + " now connected");
                                    syncDatabases();
                                    mConnected = true;
                                }
                                break;
    
                            default:
                                mConnected = false;
                                break;
                        }
                    } else mConnected = false;
                }
            }
        };
    
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            initReceiver();
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    
            if (connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null) {
                mConnected = true;
            }
            android.util.Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: SyncService created");
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            unInitReceiver();
            android.util.Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy: SyncService destroyed");
        }
    
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            android.util.Log.e(TAG, "onBind: SyncService bound");
            return null;
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
            android.util.Log.e(TAG, "onUnbind: SyncService unbound");
            return super.onUnbind(intent);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
            super.onRebind(intent);
            android.util.Log.e(TAG, "onRebind: SyncService rebound");
        }
    
        private void initReceiver() {
            IntentFilter filters = new IntentFilter();
            filters.addAction("android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED");
            filters.addAction("android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE");
            registerReceiver(mReceiver, filters);
        }
    
        private void unInitReceiver() {
            unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        }
    
        public void syncDatabases() {
            RealmResults<UserDB> users = RealmDB.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).where(UserDB.class).findAll();
    
            if (users.size() > 0) {
                int userId = users.get(0).getmUserID();
                Log.e("MESSAGE", PreferenceUtils.getInstance().getLastSyncDate());
    
                Date lastSync = null;
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    
                try {
                    lastSync = sdf.parse(PreferenceUtils.getInstance().getLastSyncDate());
                }
                catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
    
                    try {
                        lastSync = BaseFragment.FORMAT.parse(PreferenceUtils.getInstance().getLastSyncDate());
                    }
                    catch (ParseException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
    
                if (lastSync != null) {
                    Date lastSyncOffset = new Date(lastSync.getTime() + 1000);
                    /** Get all local results which have been made after the last sync date      **/
                    RealmResults<MeasurementDB> newLocalMeasurements = RealmDB.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                            .where(MeasurementDB.class).equalTo("user_ID", userId)
                            .greaterThan("dateCreated", lastSyncOffset)
                            .findAll();
    
                    /** For each measurement made after the last sync, add it to the server      **/
                    for (MeasurementDB measurement : newLocalMeasurements) {
                        TemperatureListener mListener = new TemperatureListener(measurement);
                        ApiRequest.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerNewMeasurement(measurement.getAverage(),
                                measurement.getDateCreated().toString(), mListener, mListener);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        /**
         * Temperature listener receives the local copy of the temperature item. onResponse can then
         * directly mutate the object instead of searching local db
         */
        private class TemperatureListener implements Response.Listener<Measurement>, Response.ErrorListener {
            private MeasurementDB measurement;
    
            public TemperatureListener(MeasurementDB measurement) {
                this.measurement = measurement;
            }
    
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("OnResponse", "Failure");
            }
    
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Measurement response) {
                Log.e("OnResponse", "Success");
    
                /** Update our local measurement's ID value (supplied by server)      **/
                RealmDB.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).beginTransaction();
                measurement.setMeasurement_ID(response.getmMeasurementId());
                RealmDB.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).commitTransaction();
    
                /** Update the last sync date      **/
                PreferenceUtils.getInstance().setLastSyncDate(response.getmDateCreated());
            }
        }
    }
```

***Initialisation of Service in splash activity***

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mTimedOut = true;
                finishActivity();
            }
        }, DURATION);

    /** Will sync application / cloud databases in background of app when network connected. **/
    startService(new Intent(this, SyncService.class));
    doApiWork();
}
```

***Manifest entry***

Stop with task to kill the service at the same time as the app.
Exported 'false' stops other apps from using the service.

```
    <service
        android:name=".network.SyncService"
        android:stopWithTask="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"/>
```

**EDIT**
I removed the service and left a receiver class, registered in the manifest, which triggers methods on another class when needed. However **the receiver** is only triggered in debug mode.